# ASP only shows the first gridview when var type is used

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm just a poor beginner on ASP and C#. When running below two GridViews, just get in the `default.aspx` page the Gridview1. Tried also defining DataSourceId in aspx code but without success. Looks like ASP only shows the first gridview found in the code ignoring the second one. Really appreciate your help!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using CsvHelper.TypeConversion;
using CsvHelper;
using System.IO;
sing CsvHelper.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath(@"MAD-DC01.MAD-TEST.ES.201808.csv"));
        CsvReader csvread = new CsvReader(sr);

        IEnumerable<TestRecord> record = csvread.GetRecords<TestRecord>();
        var Prints = from t in record     
                     group t by new { t.Airline, t.Kiosk_name,t.Type_print } into grupo
                     orderby grupo.Key.Airline ascending
                     select new
                            {
                                 Aerolinea = grupo.Key.Airline,
                                 Kiosko = grupo.Key.Kiosk_name,
                                 Impresion=grupo.Key.Type_print,
                                 cuenta = grupo.Sum(x => x.Prints_outs),
                            };
    var Total_Prints = from t2 in record
                       group t2 by new { t2.Airline,t2.Type_print } into grupo2
                       orderby grupo2.Key.Airline ascending
                       select new
                              {
                                  Aerolinea = grupo2.Key.Airline,
                                  Impresion = grupo2.Key.Type_print,
                                  cuenta = grupo2.Sum(x => x.Prints_outs),
                              }; 

    GridView1.DataSource = Prints.ToList();
    GridView1.DataBind();

    GridView2.DataSource = Total_Prints.ToList();
    GridView2.DataBind();
}

public class TestRecord // Test record class
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Airport { get; set; }
    public string Type_print { get; set; }
    public string Airline { get; set; }
    public string Kiosk_name { get; set; }
    public Int32 Prints_outs { get; set; }

}
```

This is the aspx part:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
 <div>

     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1">
     </asp:GridView>
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged">
     </asp:GridView>
     <br />

 </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `GridView2.DataSource =` line, and run it. When it hits the breakpoint, tell us how many items are in `Total_Prints`.

Comment: `Total_Prints`  being empty is good news. That's what I was expecting your problem to be caused by. I'm not sure what the rest of your comment means, since it seems to be the same as in your question. Whoa... Your comment was deleted.

Comment: Sorry, some issues with FF, what I meant is that if the following lines are commented;//GridView1.DataSource = Prints.ToList();
    //GridView1.DataBind();,   GridView2 is properly populated which it sounds weird. Thanks

Comment: Well computers aren't magic... Something must be putting it in the DataGrid. And at the moment, you're the only person in the world with access to your code (it's not in the question). I think you need to boil this down to a [mcve] so other people can repeat it. At the moment your question includes things which aren't relevant to the problem, like the CSV processing and the Linq queries. Read up about MCVEs and then try making your question more focused. As it says on the MCVE page, you may even find the answer yourself on the way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by replacing

```
IEnumerable<TestRecord> record = csvread.GetRecords<TestRecord>();
```

by:

```
List<TestRecord> record = new List<TestRecord>();  
while (csvread.Read()) {  
    TestRecord Record = csvread.GetRecord<TestRecord>();
    record.Add(Record);}
```